# Is linear regression the same thing as ordinary least squares in SPSS?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, spss, least-squares

I want to use a *linear regression* model, but I want to use *ordinary least squares*, which I think it is a type of linear regression. The software I use is SPSS. It only has linear regression, partial least squares and 2-stages least squares. I have no idea which one is *ordinary least squares* (OLS).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, although 'linear regression' refers to any approach to model the relationship between one or more variables, OLS is the method used to find the simple linear regression of a set of data.

Comment: Linear regression refers to any approach to model a LINEAR relationship between one or more variables. Linear regression CAN be done using OLS as can other NON-LINEAR (and hence not linear regression) models. OLS is a optimization method frequently applied when performing linear regression. However it is not the only method and others can be utilized to linear regression same as OLS is also used for NONlinear models.

Comment: @PBD10017 what are those other methods?

Answer (score 5):

Linear regression is a vast term that just says we are finding a relationship between the dependent and independent variable(s), no matter what technique we are using.

OLS is just one of the technique to do linear reg.

Lets say,

error(e) = (observed value - predicted value)

Observed values - blue dots in picture

predicted values - points on the line(vertically below to the observed values)

The vertical lines below represent 'e'. We square them -> add them and get total err. And we try to reduce this total error.

[image]

For OLS, as the name says (ordinary least squared method), here we reduce the sum of all e^2 i.e. we try to make the error least.